# mongo_client() fail with error MONGO_CONN_ADDR_FAIL

Tags: c, windows, mongodb

I want to use mongodb c driver in my project, I'm on Windows 7 so built it with command :

> scons --m32 --c99

My problem is I can't make the [Connecting example](http://api.mongodb.org/c/current/tutorial.html#connecting) work :

```
#include <stdio.h>    

#define MONGO_HAVE_STDINT
#include "mongo.h"    

int main() {
  mongo conn[1];
  int status = mongo_client( conn, "127.0.0.1", 27017 );
  printf("status %d, err %d", status, conn->err);
  mongo_destroy( conn );
  return 0;
}
```

Whether mongod is running on my machine or not, the output of executing the exe is :

> $ ./mongodb_example.exe
>   status -1, err 3

Error `3` [corresponds](http://api.mongodb.org/c/current/api/mongo_8h.html#a5e6f76bd796c89973ffb463e676237bba616d4918c05106a74cb200834ad0ec4e) to MONGO_CONN_ADDR_FAIL error code (An error occured while calling getaddrinfo()).

Any suggestion about how to connect successfully ?

**Updates:**

- version is `mongodb-mongo-c-driver-v0.8.1-0-g8f27c0f`

Comment: Which Git checkout did you build against? Good to update this in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are two things you need to do to make this work:

- When building with scons, you need to make sure you that you enable the "standard-env" target like so:

> scons --m32 --standard-env

- Secondly in your code and in addition to the `MONGO_HAVE_STDINT` that you already have, make sure you call `mongo_init_sockets()` before establishing a connection. This is required on windows.

```c
 #include <stdio.h>

 #define MONGO_HAVE_STDINT
 #include "mongo.h"

 int main() {
     mongo_init_sockets();
     mongo conn[1];

     int status = mongo_client( conn, "192.168.2.7", 27017 );
     printf("status %d, err %d", status, conn->err);
     mongo_destroy( conn );
     return 0;
 }
```

So the first part resolves the issue with `getaddrinfo()` there is an implementation included in the "standard environment". And the second part is a necessary "winsock" initialization that is required on Windows platforms. In the test files this is implemented with a defined macro.

Also make sure you are using a Python 2.7 32bit (not 64bit) as well. Not too sure how valid that is on a current `scons` release, but it doesn't hurt to be sure.

Some of this is in the documentation you may have missed [here](http://api.mongodb.org/c/current/building.html#building-on-windows), as is the fairly apt description of the [`mongo_init_sockets()`](http://api.mongodb.org/c/current/api/mongo_8h.html#a47e810efb047398d2841b91360c71ef4) function in the API documentation. Of course, looking at the test files in the distribution did not hurt.

And a little pain for me, as I don't normally build C programs on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the exact reason of the mongo failure if you print

```
       conn->errcode
       conn->errstr
```

The errcode is the equivalent of `errno` in linux or `GetLastError` in Windows.

The errstr will contain the same as a string. So you shall see something like `getaddrinfo failed with error <the return status of getaddrinfo>`

There could be multiple reasons why getaddrinfo might fail in your system. You can get these values from the man page `man gai_strerror` (`errstr` should report this)

```
       EAI_AGAIN     temporary failure in name resolution
       EAI_BADFLAGS  invalid value for ai_flags
       EAI_BADHINTS  invalid value for hints
       EAI_FAIL      non-recoverable failure in name resolution
       EAI_FAMILY    ai_family not supported
       EAI_MEMORY    memory allocation failure
       EAI_NONAME    hostname or servname not provided, or not known
       EAI_OVERFLOW  argument buffer overflow
       EAI_PROTOCOL  resolved protocol is unknown
       EAI_SERVICE   servname not supported for ai_socktype
       EAI_SOCKTYPE  ai_socktype not supported
       EAI_SYSTEM    system error returned in errno
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the mongodb c driver, so this is just a guess.  From the tutorial, it looks like you skipped the initialization step:

http://api.mongodb.org/c/current/tutorial.html

```
mongo conn[1];
mongo_init( conn );
...
mongo_client( conn, "127.0.0.1", 27017 );
```

Comment: Indeed, it seems it's the correct way to do, yet `mongo_init` is not called in the sample on the doc. Anyway, I added the line but didn't change anything.